# Word Wrapping on UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

Hi friends i have one requirement that word wrapping on label. Using  `myLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;`
 I am able to show the text in label like below

```
Designation    : I am working as iOS 
Developer
```

But i want to show

```
Designation    : I am working as iOS 
                Developer
```

Is this possible to achieve above requirement within one label?
Thanks

Comment: Set Alignment to Center of your label.

Comment: Make two different labels. One for Designation and another for work field

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi i know that cant we do it using one label

Comment: No, if center align your text, may be you have to align the character your own.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and got it solved. I have attached the screenshot. You just need to do the following:

- set `lines` property of label to `2`.
- set height and width of the label through xib and its done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, you can design your `UILabel` to have 2 lines. Then, you just need to add a new line (`"\n"`) after the word "iOS", and center-align everything? If your caption is always the same you can pre-enter it in Xcode. To add a new line, just press `alt+Enter`.

Would that be acceptable?

Comment: I am working as iOS developer is just example. Actually i am getting different text from webservices. i Just want to wrap the content like above

Comment: OK so if "Designation" is fixed, then add a `UILabel` with "Designation:" inside, and another `UILabel` with word wrapping and left-alignment on the right-hand side of the first label? And when you get responses from your Web API, you just need to update the second `UILabel`.

Comment: NO "Destinatin  :I am working as iOS developer"  is a single label

Comment: So I guess there is at least a common pattern between all responses (e.g. they all look like "aaa: bbb", or something like that), otherwise how would you determine the desired word-wrapping? Anyway I agree with other answers: you won't be able to do it using only one label, unless you parse your result text and add lines or tabs appropriately. But even in that case, two labels remains a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

**No,** it's not possible with `UILabel`, Unless workaround to this. I think, you know how to done manually. But You can't wrap the content like above. Simple answer is you can use two label.

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible.** `UILabel` just renders text according to properties that you defined. If you want to do it **ideally then use two `UILabel`s.** & Place them according to your need.